# Symfony change object injected in form using Listener

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and I have a weird thing todo, I will try to explain clearly.

I have an Entity `Website` and a `WebsiteFormType`, in this `WebsiteFormType` I have a Listener like : (in the first line of `buildForm()` in formType)

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new WebsiteListener();
```

In this listener, I need to check when a specific value is updated when the form is submited, and if this value is updated, I need to duplicate my object, for example when I update my Website and I change the `url` from `http://xxx.xx` to `http://yyyy.yy` I duplicate my first website to create the second instead of just update the field `url`.

In this Listener I use `preSubmit` and `postSubmit`.

My problem is, when I change the url I need to change the object Website linked to the form.

If `http://xxx.xx` is WebsiteA and `http://yyyy.yy` is WebsiteB, When I submit WebsiteA and I change the url, I need to change the Website object linked to the form from WebsiteA to WebsiteB....

This is for if I revalidate the form after that, it's WebsiteB which is validated and not WebsiteA.

Don't know if you understand my problem :) Thanks !

Comment: Seems like you solved this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50928464/symfony-get-data-in-controller-from-a-form-event-listener/50930407#50930407 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **Doctrine EventSubscriber** like:

```
class OrderListener implements EventSubscriber {

protected $statusChanges = false;

public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'preUpdate',
        'postUpdate',
    );
}

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $changeSet = $args->getEntityChangeSet();
    foreach ($changeSet as $key => $arr) {

        if ($key === 'status' && (int)$arr[0] !== (int)$arr[1]) {
            $this->statusChanges = true;
        }
    }
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    if ($entity instanceof Order && $this->statusChanges) {
        $repo = $args->getObjectManager()->getRepository(Action::class);
        $action = new Action();
        $action->setOrder($entity)
            ->setStatus($entity->getStatus())
            ->setCost($entity->getCost())
            ->setTimeAt(new \DateTime())
            ->setPoint($entity->getPoint())
            ->setDescription($entity->getDescription())
            ->setService($entity->getService())
        ;

        $repo->persistAndFlush($action); // custom method, you can use $args->getObjectManager()->persist($action) and $args->getObjectManager()->flush($action)
    }
}
}
```