# Symfony get data in controller from a form event listener

Tags: forms, symfony, listener

I'm using Symfony 3.4, I have a `FormType` and a Listener for this form on `preSubmit` and `postSubmit`

In my FormType I run the listener like :

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new MyListener());
```

My problem is, I need in the postSubmit or preSubmit check a condition for get un boolean, and I need this boolean in my controller after the if `($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())`.

My Listener is ok, when I submit the form the listener works well, but I don't knwo how can I get a data from the listener in my controller.

I tried to add a custom non mapped field to the form and set the value in the Listener, but when I try to set the value (true|false) I have an error : "You cannot change value of a submitted form"

I tried something with setData, getData but.. nothing

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: I suppose you could add a property to your form type class.  But it all seems rather fishy.

Comment: @Cerad I managed to solve this in that way. I added attribute in listener.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use the session for set my value in the listener, and for get this value in my controller !

Tchao !